# rabl wrap collection in json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I am using RABL to generate JSON responses. I am having trouble achieving the following structure:

```
{
  "articles": [
     {
        "created_at": "2012-10-20T15:57:31Z",
        "description": "MK DEsc",
        "id": 1,
        "title": "MK Title",
        "updated_at": "2012-10-20T15:58:14Z",
         media:[{
            id : 1,
            title : "title"
        }]
     },
     {
        "created_at": "2012-10-20T16:38:24Z",
        "description": "fdsfdffffffff",
        "id": 2,
        "title": "asdads",
        "updated_at": "2012-10-20T16:38:24Z",
         media:[{
            id : 1,
            title : "title"
        }]
     }
   ]
}
```

I have a **@artices** object which contains **media** array. i have rabl config setup like:

```
   config.include_json_root = false
   config.include_child_root = false
```

my .rabl template so far looks like this:

```
object false
node :articles do
  @articles.each do |article|
  end
end
```

i am unable to add the media info inside this structure.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to do this like so:

```
collection @articles, :root => "articles", :object_root => false
attributes *Article.column_names

child(:media) do
  attributes *Medium.column_names
end
```